# How can I better match Java types in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have a webservice that I am calling asynchronously from scala. I want to match and handle some specific fault codes that can be returned by the webservice in a `recover` block.

The error is returned as a `SoapFault` instance that is wrapped in an additional exception so essentially I need to match all exceptions where

- there is a cause which is an instance of `SoapFault`
- the `SoapFault` message matches what I want

I have this so far which is working but cumbersome:

```
call map { result => 
    // handle success
} recover {
    case e: Exception if e.getCause != null && e.getCause.isInstanceOf[SoapFault] && e.getCause.asInstanceOf[SoapFault].getMessage == "INVALID_INPUT" => {
        // handle error
    }
    case e: Exception if e.getCause != null && e.getCause.isInstanceOf[SoapFault] && e.getCause.asInstanceOf[SoapFault].getMessage == "SERVER_BUSY" => {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

How can I do this in a better way with less repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own extractor object that is similar to [lmm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27400291/22224), but which extracts the error string (rather than checking it inside the extractor object) so that I can then match specific strings within the case expression.

Extractor:

```
 object SoapFaultMessage {
    def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[String] = {
      if (t.getCause != null && t.getCause.isInstanceOf[SoapFault]) {
        Some(t.getCause.asInstanceOf[SoapFault].getMessage)
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
 .. recover {
    case SoapFaultMessage(msg) if msg == "INVALID_INPUT" => {
      //handle
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own [Extractor Object](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112). Something like (untested):

```
object FaultWithMessage {
  def apply(message: String) = new Object() {
    def unapply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
      case e: Exception if e.getCause != null &&
       e.getCause.isInstanceOf[SoapFault] &&
       e.getCause.asInstanceOf[SoapFault].getMessage == message => true
      case _ => false 
  }
}

... recover {
  case FaultWithMessage("INVALID_INPUT")() =>
    //handle that one
  case FaultWithMessage("SERVER_BUSY")() =>
    //handle that one
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't actually get this to compile: `'=>' expected but '(' found. [error] case FaultWithMessage("INVALID_INPUT")() => {`

Answer (score 1):

`recover` block handles errors that were thrown during (i.e inside) `Future` execution. As i understand from your question, although you are receiving a response which signals about some error, it doesn't throws any exception because the request itself was successful. It means that you need to handle your case inside with a `flatMap`, something like this:

```
val response = call flatMap {
  case SoapFault(error) => Future.failure(error)
  // successful response
}
```

In this case you your response would be a failure, so now you can handle your error with a `recover` block, but it's also not necessary, cause you can recover from your bad response inside `flatMap` function, cause it also returns a `Future`.

**UPDATE**

Like `lmm` proposed you can use extractor with the same name, i.e:

```
object SoapFault {
  def unapply(sf: SoapFault): Option[(Option[String], String)] = 
    Option((Option(sg.getCause), sf.getMessage))
}
```

Then deconstruct it in the block:

```
recover {
  case SoapFault(None, "INVALID_INPUT") => // process
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The SoapFaults are in fact appearing in the recover block, wrapped in a java exception. The code I have is working (using the recover block) - am looking for a better way to do it though.

Comment: @TomHaigh Is SoapFault a subtype of a Throwable? If yes, then you can match against it and use a guard to check the message, i.e `recover { case sf: SoapFault if sf.getMessage == "INVALID_INPUT" => ... }`.

Comment: Yes it is, but the problem is that it is wrapped as the cause of another exception and that makes it harder to match. i.e. (pseudo code) `Exception( cause = SoapFault( "INVALID_INPUT") )`